# Testing for existence using SELECT WHERE HAVING and NOT HAVING in a grouped subset

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

**EDIT: Sample I/O at end.**

I have data on which I need to count +1 if a particular condition exists or another condition doesn't exist. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I shred the following simplified sample XML into a temp table and validate it:

```
  <product type="1">
    <param type="1">
      <item mode="0" weight="1" />
    </param>
    <param type="2">
      <item mode="1" weight="1" />
      <item mode="0" weight="0.1" />
    </param>
    <param type="3">
      <item mode="1" weight="0.75" />
      <item mode="1" weight="0.25" />
    </param>
  </product>
```

The validation in concern is the following rule:

> For each product type, for each param type,
>   mode may be 0 & (1 || 2). In
>   other words, there may be a 0(s), but
>   then 1s or 2s are required, or there
>   may be only 1(s) or 2(s). There cannot
>   be only 0s, and there cannot be 1s
>   and 2s.

The only part I haven't figured out is how to detect if there are only 0s. This seems like a "not having" problem.

The validation code (for this part):

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT      SUM(t.ParamWeight) AS S, COUNT(1) AS C, 
                t.ProductTypeID, t.ParamTypeID, t.Mode
    FROM        @t AS t
    GROUP BY    t.ProductTypeID, t.ParamTypeID, t.Mode
),
    ...
    UNION ALL           
    SELECT      TOP (1) 1   -- only mode 0 & (1 || 2) is allowed
    FROM        t1
    WHERE       t1.Mode IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY    t1.ProductTypeID, t1.ParamTypeID
    HAVING      COUNT(1) > 1
    UNION ALL
    ...
)
SELECT      @C = COUNT(1)
FROM        t2
```

This will show if any mode 1s & 2s are mixed, but not if the group contains only a 0. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but it's evading me right now.

**EDIT:**

I thought of a "cheat" that works perfectly. I added the following to the above:

```
SELECT      TOP (1) 1   -- only mode 0 & (null || 1 || 2) is allowed
FROM        t1
GROUP BY        t1.ProductTypeID, t1.ParamTypeID
HAVING      SUM(t1.Mode) = 0
```

However, I'd still like to know how to do this without cheating.

**SAMPLE**

```
Zero  One  Two  Result
1     0    0    False
0     1    1    False
1     1    1    False
0     1    0    True
0     0    1    True
1     1    0    True
1     0    1    True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can write the following query:

```
SELECT ProductTypeID,ParamTypeID,MIN(Mode) as Has0,MAX(Mode) as M1or2,MAX(CASE WHEN Mode=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as M1
from @t
group by ProductTypeID,ParamTypeID
```

I think you can then just use these 3 columns to answer your query. If `Has0` = 0, then there's a Mode 0 value, so you need `M1or2` to be greater than 0 (if I understand correctly).

You can also verify that if `M1or2` = 2, then (I think) you want `M1` to be 0 (no Mode 1 rows were found, if a mode 2 row was found).

I think I've read your description right. If not, it might help if you add some samples of "allowed" and "disallowed" combinations.

---

```
SELECT ProductTypeID,ParamTypeID,CASE
    WHEN M1OrM2 = 2 And M1 = 1 THEN 0 /* Have both mode 2 and mode 1. Can ignore whether it has any Mode 0 */
    WHEN Has0 = 0 AND M1OrM2 = 0 THEN 0 /* Has a mode 0 and no M1 or M2 */
    ELSE 1 END /* All other combinations are allowed */
FROM (
SELECT ProductTypeID,ParamTypeID,MIN(Mode) as Has0,MAX(Mode) as M1or2,MAX(CASE WHEN Mode=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as M1
from @t
group by ProductTypeID,ParamTypeID
) t
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. If I am reading your SQL correctly, it seems to me that Has0 could be 1 if the min mode is 1. Yes... I tested it. I'll post some samples as you suggested.

Comment: @IanC - I've added a new query that has a column returning 0 for your sample "False" rows and 1 otherwise. Is that sufficient?

Comment: 50 views, and you were the only one to answer :)